# android Two-way binding cannot resolve a setter for kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

Trying to switch an app over to stateflow with databinding but get the error

Two-way binding cannot resolve a setter for kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow

xml

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/notificationsSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="@={viewModel.enable}"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:theme="@style/Switch" />
```

code

```
val enable = MutableStateFlow(true)
```

I have databinding enabled in gradle

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

liveData works fine but would like to remove it for flows

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#stateflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to upgrade your gradle version to 7.0+, as mentioned here: https://youtu.be/JnN6EFZ6DO8?t=933